# Что означает вывод строки C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe в консоли?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Перешёл на *Visual Studio 2019*.

В проектах стал замечать такую строку: ***C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe***

- Что она означает?
- Нужна ли она?
- Мешает ли она(мне по крайней эстетически)?
- Можно ли от    неё    избавиться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну а вы тип проекта какой выбрали?

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Automatically close the console when debugging stops если эстетически напрягает

Comment: @tym32167 консольное приложение.

Comment: там 2 варианта консольного прложения, вы видимо консольку от core версии создали

Comment: @tym32167 Да, вы правы. Создал от .net core. Как я понял, обычная это от .net framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[dotnet.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet?tabs=netcore21) - это утилита командной строки .NET Core, которая, среди прочего, осуществляет запуск приложений .NET Core. Дело в том, что сборка приложения .NET Core дает DLL-файлы, которые нельзя запустить напрямую, поэтому для их запуска нужен особый exe-файл.

Разумеется, это нововведение не имеет прямого отношения к Visual Studio 2019 (просто в нем рабочая нагрузка для работы с .NET Core стала устанавливаться по умолчанию). Как избавиться? Использовать проекты для классических приложений .NET. Но я не понимаю, чем она мешает - на конечный результат то она никак не влияет...